# File image broken after upload to amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 service for uploading image through my react native app.
I used the signed url sent from amazon to perform upload, so it works like that :

1. When the user opens the camera to take a picture it sends a get request to my server to get the url link.
2. I then used that signed url to make the request when the user has validated the image.

**The issue here is that the file (jpeg image) is broken after the upload in amazon S3. So the upload works fine but there is no way I can open the image.** I tried with Insomnia and it works just fine to open the image so it has to be related to my formData body that I sent through my react-native app.

Here's the code of of my component inside react native :

```
const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [1, 1],
  });

  if (!result.cancelled) {
    const resizeResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulateAsync(
      result.uri,
      [{ resize: { height: 400, width: 400 } }],
      { format: "jpeg", compress: 0.8 }
    );

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("putObject", {
      uri: resizeResult.uri,
      name: `${infoUser.id}`, // the name here shouldn't matter as it's already defined in the query (but I use the same that has be signed)
      type: "image/jpeg",
    });
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/jpeg", // I also tried : "multipart/form-data" 
      },
    };

    // results.data is the signed url

      axios.put(results.data, formData, config);
       .then((res) => console.log(res))
       .catch((e) => console.log(e.response));
```

The signature url looks like this :

```
https://bucketname.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/profile.jpg?Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIASUE*******7%2Feu-west-3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210917T094406Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=a6828c1669*********ffe641b4a&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-acl&x-amz-acl=public-read
```

I was using exactly the same formData object to send images to my server before using amazon s3 and it was working just fine.

Thank you

Comment: `formData` part looks fine. I guess there's some problem with the axios PUT request. Not sure.

Comment: Use Fiddler to capture and compare the requests, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: I just tried with Fiddler but I don't see anything when I inspect the put request, I think because of SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after many trials, I successfully uploaded my images to Amazon S3 but I don't really know how that works.

So instead of using

```
const formData = new FormData();
```

I just pass the object resizeResult as my body request.

The request looks like this :

```
 await fetch(results.data, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: resizeResult,
    })
      .then(() => console.log("success ?"))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

where the resizeResult is

```
Object {
  "height": 2112,
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540yoann84%252FoneTribe/ImageManipulator/95843dca-e89a-4cec-977b-cd2177d71f57.jpeg",
  "width": 400,
}
```